# strsplit(rquote, split = "")[[1]] in R

Tags: r

```
rquote <- "r's internals are irrefutably intriguing"
chars <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")[[1]]
```

This question has been asked before on this forum and has one answer on it but I couldn't understand anything from that answer, so here I am asking this question again.

In the above code what is the meaning of `[[1]]` ?

The program that I'm trying to run:

```
rquote <- "r's internals are irrefutably intriguing"
chars <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")[[1]]

rcount <- 0

for (char in chars) {
  if (char == "r") {
      rcount <- rcount + 1
  }
  if (char == "u") {
      break
  }
  
}

print(rcount)
```

When I don't use `[[1]]` I get the following warning message in `for` loop and I get a wrong output of **1** for `rcount` instead of **5**:

*Warning message: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between bracket \[ \] and double bracket \[\[ \]\] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)

Comment: @user438383 No it doesn't answer my question.  The answer in the link provided by you is for selecting/sub setting elements of a data frame, lists, etc.

Comment: What do you think ``strsplit(rquote, split = "")`` returns then?

Comment: @user438383 It splits the string and returns characters. That means by using ```[[1]]``` ```chars``` should only display the first element of the characters. But it doesn't, it displays all of them as it does when I don't mention the ```[[1]]``` at the end of it. But by not mentioning ```[[1]]``` I encounter an error while using ```chars``` in ```for``` loop. Other then that the output of ```chars``` as such with or without ```[[1]]``` is same.

Comment: @Salman it returns a **list**. You can access the first element of the list using [[1]] and then [[1]][2] for e.g.  the second character in the first element of the list.

Comment: @Chris I'm getting the same results for ```char``` with or without mentioning ```[[1]]```. But if I don't mention ```[[1]]``` I get an error while using ```char``` in ```for``` loop.

Comment: @user438383 let me update the question with the complete program I'm trying to run and the errors I'm encountering without using ```[[1]]```

Comment: Without `[[1]]` returns a list, that is [[1]][and the stuff inside the list as [1][2],,, With `)[[1]]` effectively `unlist`s the returned object to `character`. This then impacts what you should use in your loop, `[[` for list, `[` for vector. How granular (each character vs words) is determined by what you select as your split character.

Comment: @Chris can you post it in the answer and explain it a little bit more. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strsplit` is vectorized. That means it splits each element of a vector into a vectors. To handle this vector of vectors it returns a list in which a slot (indexed by [[) corresponds to a element of the input vector.

If you use the function on a one element vector (single string as you do), you get a one-slot list. Using [[1]] right after strsplit() selects the first slot of the list - the anticipated vector.

Unfortunately, your list `chars` works in a for loop - you have one iteration with the one slot. In `if` you compare the vector of letters against `"r"` which throws the warning. Since the first element of the comparison is TRUE, the condition holds and `rcount` is rised by 1 = your result. Since you are not indexing the letters but the one phrase, the cycle stops there.

Maybe if you run something like `strsplit(c("one", "two"), split="")` , the outcome will be more straightforward.

```
> strsplit(c("one", "two"), split="")
[[1]]
[1] "o" "n" "e"

[[2]]
[1] "t" "w" "o"

> strsplit(c("one", "two"), split="")[[1]] 
[1] "o" "n" "e"

> strsplit(c("one"), split="")[[1]][2] 
[1] "n"
```

Comment: Thanks that clears up a lot of things. Can you explain this part a bit more: "Since you are not indexing the letters but the one phrase, the cycle stops there." Does not stating ```[[1]]``` index the whole phrase as one and not element wise?

Comment: When you add `[[1]]` after `strsplit()` your `chars` will be a vector of letters (as in my 2nd example) and cycle will go letter by letter.

Answer (score 1):

We'll start with the below as data, without [[1]]:

```
rquote <- "r's internals are irrefutably intriguing"
chars2 <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")
class(chars2)
[1] "list"
```

It is always good to have an estimate of your return value, your above '5'. We have both `length` and `lengths`.

```
length(chars2)
[1] 1     # our list
lengths(chars2)
[1] 40    # elements within our list
```

We'll use `lengths` in our for loop for counter, and, as you did, establish a receiver vector outside the loop,

```
rcount2 <- 0
for (i in 1:lengths(chars2)) {
    if (chars2[[1]][i] == 'r') {
      rcount2 <- rcount2 +1
       }
    if (chars2[[1]][i] == 'u') {
      break
      }
}
print(rcount2)
[1] 6
length(which(chars2[[1]] == 'r')) # as a check, and another way to estimate
[1] 6
```

Now supposing, rather than list, we have a character vector:

```
chars1 <- strsplit(rquote, split = '')[[1]]
length(chars1)
[1] 40
rcount1 <- 0
for(i in 1:length(chars1)) {
if(chars1[i] == 'r') {
rcount1 <- rcount1 +1
}
if (chars1[i] == 'u') {
break
}
}
print(rcount1)
[1] 5
length(which(chars1 == 'r'))
[1] 6
```

Hey, there's your '5'. What's going on here? Head scratch...

```
all.equal(chars1, unlist(chars2))
[1] TRUE
```

That `break` should just give us 5 'r' before a 'u' is encountered. What's happening when it's a list (or does that matter...?), how does the final r make it into rcount2?

And this is where the fun begins. Jeez. break for coffee and thinking. Runs okay. Usual morning hallucination. They come and go. But, as a final note, when you really want to torture yourself, put `browser()` inside your for loop and step thru.

```
Browse[1]> i
[1] 24
Browse[1]> n
debug at #7: break
Browse[1]> chars2[[1]][i] == 'u'
[1] TRUE
Browse[1]> n
> rcount2
[1] 5
```